# How pass $variables for all functions with constructor in controller (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, controller, php-carbon

i would like pass a variable in another function, i use __construct function for it, but my browser return "Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $startingAt ]]". Thanks for your help !

My Controller :

```
protected $startingAt;


public function __construct($startingAt)
{
    $this->startingAt = $startingAt;
}

public function index()
{
    return view('index');
}

public function startingAt()
{
    $this->startingAt = Carbon::now();
    return $this->startingAt;
}
```

My blade.pĥp:

```
<form action="{{ route('starting.race') }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    @method('post')
    <button class="bg-indigo-600 text-white font-bold px-3 rounded-full" type="submit" name="submit">Start</button>
</form>
```

My web.php :

```
Route::get('/', [\App\Http\Controllers\CarbonController::class, 'index'])->name('index.race');

Route::post('/start', [\App\Http\Controllers\CarbonController::class, 'startingAt'])->name('starting.race');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.6 "Unresolvable dependency resolving..." when doing dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50660549/laravel-5-6-unresolvable-dependency-resolving-when-doing-dependency-injecti)

Comment: I only use a controller for the moment because i'm beginner :x

Comment: Do you want to access this function to another function at same class?

Comment: i want access on $variable result by another function at the same class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just call the function you made to fill the variable in your constructor and remove the parameter `$startingAt` from the contructor method.

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->startingAt();
}
```

Comment: its works but i would like collect $variable result not the function it isnt possible ?

Comment: @ValentinLeguy collect from where ?

Comment: i would like take $startingAt result from another function (i want collect $startingAt and $endingAt results and display them on another function) and at the same class

Comment: oops sorry, i just see how to collect params from another function lmao, thanks for you help !